# Why won't APEX Collection build?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using 2 APEX Collections to run queries that are then used in multiple regions of my page to display different subsets of data. The first is the main query, and the second just aggregates the entire data set based on demographic characteristics.

The second is long enough that I have to split it between 2 hidden items that I then concatenate in my PL/SQL function body. I've done this multiple times before, but this time the query just will not run. I suspect it's due to the way the concatenation happens, but I'm unable to understand why or how to address it.

Here is an example of the code (truncated):

```
<!--hidden item 1, P623057_TOTALS_Q-->
select gender as group_label,
    'gender' as category,
    count(gender) as total,
    0 as schoolid
from staff
group by gender
union

<!--hidden item 2, P623057_TOTALS_Q2-->
select ethnicity,
    'ethnicity' as category,
    count(ethnicity),
    0 as schoolid
from staff
group by ethnicity
```

And my PL/SQL function:

```
DECLARE
    l_query varchar2(32767) := :P623057_TOTALS_Q || :P623057_TOTALS_Q2;
begin
    IF APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => 'DEMTOT') THEN
            APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION (p_collection_name => 'DEMTOT');
    end if;
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B (
        p_collection_name => 'DEMTOT', 
        p_query => l_query);
End;
```

I have tried:

- Adding spaces/returns at the beginning/end of either hidden item (when saved/closed APEX trims that extraneous space)
- Concatenating a line feed (chr(10))
- Moving the UNION between the hidden items
- Adding a tab before the UNION operator

One time it worked after adding a CR/LF to P623057_TOTALS_Q2, but once I reloaded the page it stopped working.

The error I get is:
`ora_sqlerrm: ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query_b Error:ORA-20104: create_collection_from_query ParseErr:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06512`. I have verified that the query is valid.

I've since sort of given up and just let the aggregation that caused my totals query to get too large run in the region that uses it, but I'd love to understand why it was doing this and what I could do to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you don't put the query in a page item but directly in the pl/sql block that creates the collection ?

Comment: No, I get a 'Value too long by 682 characters' error (which is the same error I get in the hidden items).

EDIT - that was unclear - it's the same error I get when I try to do it all in a single hidden item.

Comment: That error is a code editor limitation. You could put the query in a package variable and call it that way.

Comment: Thanks for that. My PL/SQL knowledge is next to nil, and I'm having trouble finding good examples of this type of work when I search; do you have anywhere you could send me or some example code you would be willing to share? I'm seeing some code where I `CREATE PACKAGE my_package IS my_var [some variable type... vachar2(4000)?]; END'` but that doesn't work. Do I need that in a DEFINE block? Again, I very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of your code becomes too large then it's advised to move the code to packages.
Here is an example of a procedure in a package that populates a collection based on the emp/dept sample dataset. Rename to useful names for your applciation.

1. Create the package

```
create or replace package mypkg AS
  PROCEDURE P1_POPULATE_COLLECTION;
END mypkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY MYPKG AS

  PROCEDURE P1_POPULATE_COLLECTION AS
      l_query varchar2(32767) := q'!SELECT ename, 'gender' as category FROM EMP!';
  BEGIN
      IF APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => 'EMP') THEN
              APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION (p_collection_name => 'EMP');
      END IF;
      APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY_B (
          p_collection_name => 'EMP', 
          p_query => l_query);
  END P1_POPULATE_COLLECTION;

END MYPKG;
/
```

2. Add a page process

Add a before-header page process of type pl/sql with code

```
mypkg.p1_populate_collection;
```

Putting queries in page items might work but I wouldn't call that good practice at all. My advice is to get up to speed on pl/sql - it isn't hard at all and it will make your life as an apex developer *a lot* easier. If you get stuck there is always stack overflow ;)

Comment: Excellent advice, which I will definitely take!

Thanks very much for that code, I greatly appreciate it (and all your help on my questions, you’ve been a huge help every time you’ve offered your expertise!)